# How to paste information into filtered CHeaderCtrl

Tags: mfc

We have an MFC application that uses the CHeaderCtrl and have been using the HDS_FILTERBAR style to filter data.  Works great.  But our users want to be able to paste in text into the filter cell.  I have not found a way to get a pointer to any CEdit-type of control here so that I can call >Paste.  I have managed to detect a Control-V while in the filter in the application's ::PreTranslateMessage.  There is a way to send text to the filter by way of a CHeaderCtrl->SetItem call, but this will immediately launch the filter.  I just want to be able to paste text.

So...I tried (I was desperate) using keybd_event and SendInput to force keystrokes.  This worked but had undesirable side effects, probably due to MFC's message handling, and in my case, the user already had the Control + V pressed down.  But in just sending the letter 'A', and forcing the SHIFT key, I accidently discovered that the CHeaderCtrl's filter does support a paste if you:

CONTROL + SHIFT + V

The problem is its hard to do, and hard to tell my users to do this.

I can simulate this sequence using keybd_event, but again, its real quirky.

Can anyone find a way to either get access to the CEdit (if there even is one) to a filtered CHeaderCtrl or know of another workaround ? I tried using a spy utility, but was not sure what to look for. Sorry for the long post.

Comment: Do you have Ctrl+V in your accelerator4 list? Than this is the Problem.
The message might be interpreted by your global accelerator. So you might check in the PreTranslateMessage Routine who has the Focus and in this case directly call TranslateMessage/DispatchMessage

Comment: Yes, that was it.  I feel so stupid.  I have not checked the accelerator table in years, and we don't even use Control-V directly. Thank you so much for thinking of the obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So remove Ctrl+V from the accelerator list and you can handle it inside the control...
(Answer added according to the comment).